# Load image from potentially-null interpolated URL values in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to load image with two different scope variables values as follows:

```
$scope.image.baseURL = "http://localhost/myApp/public/";
$scope.image.relativeURL = "app/images/template/001/section.png";
```

The values are dynamically loaded, and they are sometimes undefined. In the case that either value is undefined, no image should be loaded.

1. Consider following example:

   ```
   <img ng-src="{{image.baseURL + image.relativeURL}}"/>
   ```

   This doesn't work. In this case, if `relativeURL` is undefined, it resolves the first scope variable value and tries to access it with only the `baseURL` value. I get an console error with a 400 status code due to a request to `http://localhost/myApp/public/`.
2. Consider following example:

   ```
   <img src="{{image.baseURL + image.relativeURL}}"/>
   ```

   This doesn't work, either. In this case, the compiler is not able to resolve scope variables until Angular loads, so the URL with curly braces is used to make a request. I get an console error with a 400 status code due to a request to `http://localhost/myApp/public/image.baseURL%20+%20image.relativeURL`.
3. Another question recommended that I use a function on the scope, like this:

   ```
   <img ng-src="getImageUrl()"/>
   $scope.getImageUrl = function() { return $scope.baseURL + $scope.relativeURL}
   ```

   This still doesn't work because I get an the same error, this time with a request to `http://localhost/myApp/public/getImageUrl()`.

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: You don't need `{{` and `}}` for `ng-*` attributes

Comment: @Tushar it's not true, ng-href, ng-src need `{{}}`

Comment: Not able to reproduce it. Check http://jsfiddle.net/aetnxxep/

Comment: @Shreyas I checked your fiddle, it's working. Actually I am doing these image loading in dynamically included template.

Comment: Have you found the solution? If not, try using $timeout while assigning your values in controller.

Answer (score 4):

The `ngSrc` directive has two capabilities:

1. Obviously, the core functionality is simple: it waits for Angular to load, then it performs interpolation on the attribute value and sets the `src` attribute to the result.
2. A lesser-known feature is that if *any* angular interpolation expression evaluates to `undefined`, no `src` attribute will be generated. **This behavior is only present in versions 1.3 and greater.**

Therefore, it would *seem* that your example using the `{{image.baseURL + image.relativeURL}}` would work as intended, but it doesn't. Why?

Well, the key is that in order for the angular expression to "short circuit" and be ignored, a *whole expression* must evaluate to `undefined`. If `baseURL` is defined, but `relativeURL` isn't, the result will simply be the string "undefined" concatenated onto the end of `baseURL`. Obviously, this string is *not* undefined, so Angular will render the `src` attribute.

Fortunately, this is easy to fix: instead of doing string concatenation within the expression, just use two expressions.

```js
angular.module('Sample', [])
  .controller('SampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.image = {
      baseURL: 'https://example.com/',
      relativeURL: undefined
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Sample" ng-controller="SampleController">
  <img ng-src="{{image.baseURL}}{{image.relativeURL}}">
</div>
```

Notice that no `src` attribute is created!

However, it is true that sometimes, the amount of processing you need to do within Angular expressions is too heavy. In that case, you can use a function, but to take advantage of this behavior, you *must* return `undefined` if you don't want any `src` attribute to appear.

```js
angular.module('Sample', [])
  .controller('SampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var image = {
      baseURL: 'https://example.com/',
      relativeURL: undefined
    };
    $scope.fullUrl = function () {
      if (image.baseURL && image.relativeURL) {
        return image.baseURL + image.relativeURL;
      }
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Sample" ng-controller="SampleController">
  <img ng-src="{{fullUrl()}}">
</div>
```

When the branch *isn't* taken, the function doesn't explicitly return, so it will evaluate to `undefined`, and Angular will not create a `src` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Check working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2g8qygg/).

In [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) documentation:

> ngSrc template any string which can contain {{}} markup.

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
.controller('JoyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.base = 'https://www.google.com.hk/images/srpr/';
    $scope.image = 'logo11w.png';
    $scope.getImageUrl = function () {
        return $scope.base + $scope.image;
    };
}]);
```

In HTML:

```
<div ng-app="Joy" ng-controller="JoyCtrl">
    <img ng-src="{{getImageUrl()}}"/>
</div>
```